# Create a git patch for particular file types

Tags: git, repository, diff, patch

How could I create a git patch from thousands of changed files but only include specific file types. For example I only need .cp and .js file types that are changed within my repository to be included in the patch.

Comment: @jthill with all due respect I think the question is slightly different from the one you mentioned.

Comment: I see that you're correct, my apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's so simple. If you want to include only specific file types in your patch, you could do so by following the below syntax:

```
> git diff  0fa393b64893 940dd1e792b -- '*.cp' '*.js' > my.patch
> git apply my.patch
```

You need to navigate to your repository directory in your bash.

```
> cd /c/projects/myproject/
```